# Why do some languages specify a function or subroutine preamble?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design

I am not familiar with compiler design or implementation problems outside of an academic introduction many years ago.

In C I might define a function thusly:

```c
int foo(int bar) {
    return bar * 2;
}
```

But in Rust, I would write:

```rust
fn foo(bar: i32) -> i32 {
    return bar * 2;
}
```

Notice that my function definition in Rust required the 'fn' preamble, while no such identifier was used in the C example.

Plenty of other languages throughout the ages have exhibited this same requirement. Perl, Python, Rust, Basic, all have this requirement (sub, def, fn, sub).

Why do some programming languages require a specific preamble before the declaration of a function? Is there a technical reason that make this design attractive, or is it simply a stylistic choice?

Comment: Like most aspects of syntax, it's simply a stylistic choice. However, a language's grammar has to be consistent, in the sense that it must not be ambiguous. So some choices determine other choices.

Comment: Also, note that C *does* require a "preamble" in a function definition: the type. It's not a *keyword*, but it nevertheless serves as a clear signal to the parser that the statement is a function declaration. (Oversimplifying, no other statement type can start with two adjacent identifiers.)

Comment: You can think of it as punctuation. It doesn't carry intrinsic meaning on its own, and yet it's useful.

Comment: I object to flagging this question as being opinion-based. I am specifically not asking if function preambles are good or bad. I am asking if there are specific technical requirements for their use in some languages or others, as a reflection of the underlying compiler design, or if they are stylistic choices made by the designers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in human languages, in technical languages it would be difficult to determine which language's grammar is better. In C, if you have

```
<thetype> <thename>(<theparameters>)
```

is a proper function header. If you have

```
<thetype> <thename>
```

(without the paranthesis), then it is a variable (assuming this is the full command with possibly an assignment being added).

As we can see, C's syntax does not require you to specify with an explicit `function`, `fn` or `fun` or `func` keyword that the code that follows is a function, because the syntax makes that perfectly clear given the rules of the language.

Since we have found a language where the `function` (or similar) keyword is unnecessary in order to specify that the code that follows is a function, we have also proven that there is no technical necessity to use such a keyword.

Nevertheless, some other languages might be not so clear about this. For instance, in basic you can implement a `Sub` (that is, a procedure) or a `Function`. Here we have an explicit distinction between the two in the language's rules, but it does not seem to be a technical necessity, even if we take Basic's language rules into account in general.

One could implement a compiler that searches for the `Return` keyword inside a `Function` and handle the difference between the `Sub` and the `Function` internally. But the engineers planning the language have chosen not to do so, maybe they were preferring the language to be explicit, as other keyword usages (such as `IsNot Nothing` or `AndAlso`) suggests, but, since I was not involved at the planning of that particular language, I cannot be sure.

In general, to summarize the answer: there is no technical reason that would force the inventors of languages to use a `function` or similar keyword explicitly, but they may choose to do so, possibly with the reason of being explicit, but the exact reason is only known by those who were part of the planning or who have been informed about this.

Comment: “Like in human languages, in technical languages it would be difficult to determine which language's grammar is better.” — No, I disagree. Rust’s syntax is *clearly* better, for several reasons. In hindsight, C’s declaration grammar was a huge mistake.

Comment: @KonradRudolph if you prefer writing and reading explicit code, then yes. But, if you prefer to type less characters, then C seems to have the better syntax. It boils down to what you prefer. So, since it really depends on preference, the different preferences result to differences of result of the comparison. This is why it is difficult to determine which syntax is better.

Comment: @KonradRudolph would you mind backing up your claims with sources/reasons?

Comment: C's declaration syntax can be hard to read in some cases, but you can generally use `typedef` to make complex declarations more readable. However, it turned out not to extend well to C++, as shown by the existence of the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), an ambiguity which illustrates how different syntactic rules can have unfortunate interactions. But I'm not taking sides on which syntax is "better"; that can only be answered by first proposing a universal optimality criterion, and I doubt that such a thing exists.

Comment: @Finomnis I don’t know which sources you’d accept but it’s pretty uncontroversial. Keywords allow parses to synchronise their state in case of user errors, which allows compilers to produce more readable error messages. C’s syntax makes this fundamentally harder, and things like C++’s most vexing parse is a further consequence of that. Meanwhile, C’s syntax also leads to complexities when nesting types, which doesn’t exist in other programming languages. That’s why sites like e.g. https://cdecl.org/ exist for C, but for no other language.

Comment: @Finomnis …  Notice also how every mainstream language since C (except those that explicitly inherited C’s syntax) has keywords to introduce functions. This isn’t a coincidence, it is the result of conscious decision-making.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks :) yah, that satisfied my curiosity ;)